# Installing Perl 6 to MSYS2 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gtk3, raku, msys2, nativecall

I want to develop a GTK+3 app on Windows 10 using Perl 6 and its NativeCall library. I have installed MSYS2 and GTK+3 on it and could run an example GTK+3 C program using it. But I couldn't install Perl 6 on MSYS2. I have tried to search web for related blogs or posts but I couldn't find any solution. How can I install Perl 6 (Rakudo) on MSYS2?

Comment: If you just say "I couldn't install", that's not giving people a lot to go on.  Could you be more specific as to what you have tried and what the errors were?

Comment: You are right. I was just looking for a step-by-step guide. Anyway; I gave up MSYS2 and decided to use Ubuntu for my purpose.

Comment: “Ubuntu” as in “Ubuntu on Windows” or a separate OS altogether?

Comment: Separate OS. I read that "Ubuntu on Windows" didn't support GTK+ or any other graphical toolkit.